# Order of NSFetchedResultController delegates didChange: atSectionIndex:

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an odd situation and am asking myself if I did something wrong. I have an NSFetchedResultsController and a a delegate assigned. The delegate receives the function calls that sections have been added correctly but the order of the messages seems to be undefined.

```
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>,
                    didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo,
                    atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int,
                    for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType)
```

Say my initial fetch resulted in 3 sections [0,1,2]. Now I receiveing updates about changes like so:

- .insert action for sectionIndex 4
- .insert action for sectionIndex 3

I am trying to track a view model based on the changes, so I don't know what I need to do here. How can I add section 4 before section 3 was added. The problem is, if I just add a placeholder section 3, then add section 4 I don't know if I have to add a new section 3, moving all subsequent sections by one or if that is the call that I missed before inserting section 4.

The documentation says noting about the order but I would have expected the updates to be in order so that I can track the changes to a local array.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`NSFetchedResultsController` was designed/implemented/tested specifically to drive the data source of `UITableView`. From the docs:

```
While table views can be used in several ways, fetched results controllers primarily assist you with a primary list view.
```

To answer your question, I don't think you're doing anything wrong but I think you're trying to reverse engineer some secret sauce deep in `UITableView`'s implementation.

Comment: Probably, you are right. Still unfortunate because there is much use in a SwiftUI view model being driven by `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I see nothing in the documentation about order of operations, so we must presume that there is no guarantee. But per the documentation for [`NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate), implementing `controllerDidChangeContent(_:)`, followed by a table reload, looks like the way to go, instead of using `controller(:didChange:atSectionIndex:for:)`. Or if you do want to continue catching each section insertion, batch up those changes until you get the `didChangeContent()` call.

Comment: The question still remains how the tableView will know what to do in my example the result could be: `[0,1,2,3,4]` or `[0,1,2,3,3',4]`. If order is not guaranteed how would you know when you have to insert a new section unless you wait until the `didChange` notification and just query the current state from scratch again.

Comment: Listen for the individual section updates, and keep track of what you need to do. Defer UI updates until the `didChange`. This smells like it could be a premature optimization, btw: is the performance unacceptable if you query state from scratch?

Comment: Unfortunately, the whole reason I am doing this is because performance is not acceptable. My use case is background processes firing many `save()` events and I don't want to trigger an update of everything all the time. Anyways, thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: You may have already tried this, but I would suggest using an intermediate ManagedObjectContext to catch all of the background processes' `save()` events and coalesce them periodically to the view's MOC. And take a look at the logging available with Xcode Core Data launch arguments. A completely different approach would be to batch your insertions/updates (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/batch_processing).